# ¿Como hacer un recorrido en un array en vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Hola amigos de la comunidad quisiera que me ayuden en este tema, quiero hacer un recorrido en un array que es llamado con un metodo:

```
        getListarVent(){
            axios.get(route('ventasDashboard.get')).then((response)=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                
                this.vent[0].data = response.data;  

            });
        },
```

y quisiera que en la parte de response.data solo se almacene una parte del array en este caso ses la "sumaTotal", quisiera ver que alternativa puedo usuar, para no hacerlo uno por uno "response.data[0].sumaTotal"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: voy a refrasearte.. para que yo no tenga que escribir el for a mano, y encuentre una funcion que haga el for por mi ;)

Comment: Un ciclo `for` debería ser suficiente. Lo haces con un `response.data[i].sumaTotal` y vas redefiniendo el array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede haber más de una forma de hacer lo que buscas, y la solución es bastante simple.

Como te mencionan en los comentarios, puedes recorrer mediante un bucle `for` el resultado de la consulta de `Axios`.

Ejecuta el siguiente código, y verifica si hace lo que esperabas:

```js
let response = {}

response.data = [
  {
    "sumaTotal": "82.70",
    "numVentas": 1,
    "fechaRegistro": "02-02-2022"
  },
  {
    "sumaTotal": "82.70",
    "numVentas": 1,
    "fechaRegistro": "03-02-2022"
  }
]

let arraySumaTotal = []

for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length ; i++) {    
  arraySumaTotal.push(response.data[i].sumaTotal)
}

console.log(arraySumaTotal)
```

Lo que hago aquí básicamente es ir recorriendo el array `response.data` con el ciclo `for` mientras le haces `.push` al nuevo array llamado `arraySumaTotal` el cual solo contendrá las propiedades `sumaTotal`.